# Android Bluetooth Input/Outputstream: Sent ~1400 bytes, received 1008

Tags: android, bluetooth, arrays, inputstream, outputstream

I'm trying to send data between two Android 4.0.1 phones, and when I send my data, I don't receive the full array on the other side.

My code:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
int bytes;

bytes = inputStream.read(buffer);
// bytes = 1008
// buffer[1008..4095] = 0 
// =================== other side =============================
byte[] message = Tools.concatByteArray(response, authorizationMessage);

// Debug tells me that the array has 1400 bytes
outputStream.write(message);
outputStream.flush();
```

Messages in debug are:

```
[102, -32, 27, 23, 31, 111, -43, 124, 105, -122, 89, 13, 80, 62, 107, -21, 44, -93, -24, 100, -28, 18, -10, -55, 8, -7, 95, -82, -127, -125, -13, -14, 82, 93, -112, 33, 5, -43, 82, -89, -60, 111, 61, 5, 65, 1, -105, -65, -77, -119, 126, -118, -67, 32, -115, 106, -10, 75, 44, 101, 60, -110, -71, -27, 44, -111, 83, 83, 99, -25, -71, 12, -101, -35, -79, -115, 99, 107, 21, 118, -52, -107, -51, -122, 106, 12, 43, 23, 111, -60, -79, -20, 57, -28, 99, -106, -87, 74, -18, 71, 44, -26, -6, 80, -124, 34, -69, 27, 46, -15, -97, -71, 84, 30, -121, -36, 65, -46, 66, -34, 69, -127, -16, 100, 114, 38, -110, -24, -34, 82, 69, -75, 108, 42, 83, 103, -14, -54, 10, 85, 107, -1, 42, 41, 106, 4, 65, 122, -101, -45, 19, 32, -110, 61, 53, 73, -97, -119, -63, 96, 55, -103, -59, -84, -35, -64, 47, -58, -38, 8, 9, 3, 82, -109, -78, 124, 69, -2, -74, -55, 72, -26, 33, -110, 92, -48, 87, 81, 39, 95, -45, 121, -82, -75, -79, -104, 93, 37, -118, 108, 20, -49, -96, 74, -120, -89, 110, -36, 115, 69, 98, 99, -21, 48, 112, -42, -124, 7, 18, 32, -126, -47, 87, -33, -5, -83, -2, 61, 85, -31, -18, 109, -75, 75, -16, 57, 67, 90, 98, 54, -27, -79, 111, -119, 67, 106, -3, 43, 56, -56, -115, -118, 15, -80, -83, -83, 101, 116, 46, -89, 113, -38, 33, -49, -114, -90, -20, 59, -50, 27, -98, 41, 116, -73, 48, 92, -104, -5, 74, -91, 75, 49, 35, 9, 65, -47, 35, 17, 27, -112, -64, -80, -104, 0, -109, 55, 89, 11, 42, -22, 86, -125, 127, 1, -27, -64, 21, -119, 15, 79, 27, -2, -18, 36, 77, 47, -32, 81, -117, -107, 112, 52, 125, -116, -83, -34, -15, 31, -37, 19, -65, 28, -93, -102, 12, 83, 108, 88, -5, 121, -107, -71, -3, 65, 18, -99, -92, 103, -9, 57, 90, 93, 29, 13, -14, 122, 126, -32, 54, 90, -126, 10, -123, -94, 46, -90, -11, -93, -75, 23, -18, 36, 51, 8, 115, -122, -44, -59, -99, -127, 33, -107, -116, 11, -94, -94, 92, -51, 94, -15, -72, 78, 82, 10, -14, -81, -121, -57, -55, 4, -64, 89, -69, -26, 24, 10, -27, -44, 80, 3, 11, -7, 127, 109, 3, -20, -52, 92, 31, -80, -13, -127, -73, -61, -11, -1, 110, 52, 100, -72, -73, 29, -98, -55, -39, 14, 48, 71, 79, -60, -29, -61, 97, -48, -59, -61, -117, 89, -73, 95, -4, -8, -57, 21, -26, 31, 37, 32, -72, 77, -41, -111, 99, 62, 98, 117, -63, 103, -124, -96, -111, -84, -1, 7, -20, 47, 57, 15, -59, 66, 53, 47, 97, -94, 7, -56, 124, 83, 72, 81, 101, 77, 96, -40, 67, 112, 112, 112, 16, -127, 72, -127, -98, -73, -125, 78, 84, 107, 125, 12, 121, 57, -17, 68, -41, -75, -28, -26, -3, 125, -97, 82, -53, 8, -124, -118, -1, 47, 19, 64, -18, 38, 45, 84, 85, -52, 105, 109, -61, 1, -32, 72, -107, 20, -102, -40, -47, 67, 111, -72, -92, 88, -30, 61, -82, 116, -2, -127, 35, 72, 35, -51, 24, 21, -87, 21, 63, -82, -2, 70, -70, -118, -64, 15, -44, 93, 108, 62, -51, 84, -15, 72, 7, 102, -107, -112, -7, -72, 84, -24, -22, 53, 68, 68, 38, -64, 71, 27, 73, 40, -86, 111, -56, 22, 49, 88, -119, -42, 9, 121, 82, 22, -35, 113, 5, -112, 12, -71, 17, -31, 92, -4, 48, -40, -44, -41, -60, -82, -116, 5, 117, -95, -28, -54, 45, -32, 39, -119, -25, 126, -40, 95, -97, -88, -58, -3, -81, -84, -82, -122, 122, -20, 11, 74, 85, 117, -75, 77, 39, -81, -72, 108, 123, 104, 65, -60, 81, -104, 41, 63, -62, 65, 43, -84, -64, 35, -63, 78, -111, 55, -1, 123, 73, 125, -92, -76, -81, -106, 103, -125, 105, -102, 112, -57, 69, 30, 13, 41, 65, -47, 121, -111, 94, -21, -16, -87, -39, 87, 91, 48, 116, -80, 100, 25, -64, 87, 63, -7, -6, -104, 41, -17, -13, 32, 106, -35, -35, -119, 107, 66, 116, 119, -68, -94, 116, 40, 117, -36, 89, 69, -47, -47, -78, 89, -16, -15, -25, -29, -53, -72, -105, -83, -67, 110, 52, 76, -92, 90, 93, -34, -18, 105, -92, -76, -55, -80, 117, -122, -94, -59, 100, 96, -85, -16, 116, 84, 55, -72, -55, -63, 54, 111, -1, 116, 6, 5, 23, -62, -109, 93, -127, 113, 96, 66, -16, 29, -95, -77, -13, 74, -90, 122, -37, -109, -40, 46, -108, -73, 45, 91, -23, -117, 85, 111, -23, 83, 3, -75, -51, -68, 102, 81, -122, -38, 12, -115, -34, 91, -29, -114, 124, -31, 93, -92, -124, -31, -17, 23, 65, -27, -6, 105, 0, -127, -110, 66, 59, -107, -95, 38, 69, -58, 106, 55, 105, 23, -19, -38, 118, 85, -5, -14, 126, -42, 84, -11, 121, 75, 72, -88, 29, 20, -107, -128, -109, -124, 120, -109, -91, -102, -56, -45, -103, 61, -71, 123, -66, -75, 58, -84, -61, 59, 12, 74, 78, -58, -73, -59, -14, -24, 78, 37, 123, -56, -98, 120, -25, -49, -115, 41, 66, -90, -12, -88, -62, 44, 81, -59, 67, 78, -57, -128, -123, -108, -94, -34, 108, 115, 78, 112, -95, 48, 80, 94, 6, -84, 46, -6, 31, -35, 7, 75, -57, -41, -3, 3, -67, -89, 15, -36, -111, 115, -126, -111, 61, 42, 84, -107, -90, -103, 44, -29, -21, 75, 96, 42, 34, 74, 117, -10, -63, 122, -119, -78, -50, -78, 39, 112, 10, 29, -3, 79, -119, 50, 121, 29, -96, -87, 114, 86, -65, -104, -80, -43, -123, 41, 106, -22, 2, -2, -38, -30, 97, 44, -51, -115, 75, 86, -117, 68, -69, 57, 1, 79, 12, 95, -112, 92, 75, 84, -116, -74, 57, 73, 46, -71, 61, 97, 115, -71, 112, -96, 33, 29, -105, -18, -89, -27, 35, 42, -113, -22, -78, -27, 22, 5, 45, -56, -70, -82, -18, -40, -80, -30, -91, -8, -77, -18, 115, -81, 101, -46, 82, -90, 30, -105, -99, -25, -103, -110, -50, -66, 84, -57, -5, -22, -128, -18, 69, 52, -11, -111, -24, -85, -1, 12, 72, -31, -97, 81, -29, 68, -80, 73, 7, -55, 45, -33, -73, 127, 2, 4, 56, 74, -19, 78, -73, 106, 58, 10, 10, -75, -60, -16, 98, 46, 82, -45, 15, 79, 90, 43, -53, 37, -25, -29, 50, -72, 120, 73, -20, 110, 96, -48, -38, -5, 39, 18, -47, -109, 89, -45, 74, 60, -30, 85, -16, -57, -24, 118, 44, -67, -38, 72, -124, -76, -124, -78, -18, 18, -55, -7, -23, -63, -82, -17, -58, 36, 103, 100, -116, -73, 85, -22, 43, 24, 41, 1, -123, 52, 125, 68, 5, -80, 21, -124, 72, -82, 121, 66, 103, 123, 82, -37, -79, -124, -67, 66, 15, -29, 59, -90, -48, -37, -12, 40, 20, 66, 28, -95, 28, 68, -26, 80, 74, 64, 122, 58, 2, 91, -45, 115, 87, 77, 107, 5, -1, 68, 119, 109, -113, 94, 48, -67, 6, -120, -76, -34, -49, -121, 103, -25, 60, 119, -11, -99, -74, -104, 123, 21, -100, 77, -51, -122, -32, 16, 74, -90, -21, -9, 20, 82, -112, -1, -116, -119, 68, -21, 3, -65, 101, 30, 14, 49, -34, 38, -13, 105, 21, -98, 23, 114, 119, -109, 26, 91, -41, 73, 90, -34, -119, -66, 47, 38, 57, 111, 34, -77, -74, -100, 56, 30, -74, 79, 100, 73, -69, 28, -100, 10, 96, 68, -109, -87, -53, -44, -13, 48, -16, 79, -52, -60, -105, 23, 73, 32, -60, -47, -29, -17, 32, 52, -105, 118, -66, 82, 0, -96, 14, 74, -61, -107, 13, 14, -30, -5, 34, 78, 112, 0, -114, 109, 71, -7, 33, 110, -76, -66, 19, -117, 0, -124, -93, -116, -94, 12, 86, 4, 106, -77, -31, 64, -37, -105, 2, -99, -37, 42, 9, 103, 12, -44, -59, -23, -121, 31, 2, 60, 28, -96, -77, 16, -78, -75, 43, 1, 108, 52, 11, -18, 11, -79, -2, 106, 111, -51, 16, 12, 108, 79, 18, 49, 112, -67, 6, 66, 124, 98, 34, -94, 10, 17, 125, 93, -57, -58, 34, 86, -100, 101, -94, -97, 117, 48, 68, 35, 14, -46, -75, 45]

and for buffer:
[102, -32, 27, 23, 31, 111, -43, 124, 105, -122, 89, 13, 80, 62, 107, -21, 44, -93, -24, 100, -28, 18, -10, -55, 8, -7, 95, -82, -127, -125, -13, -14, 82, 93, -112, 33, 5, -43, 82, -89, -60, 111, 61, 5, 65, 1, -105, -65, -77, -119, 126, -118, -67, 32, -115, 106, -10, 75, 44, 101, 60, -110, -71, -27, 44, -111, 83, 83, 99, -25, -71, 12, -101, -35, -79, -115, 99, 107, 21, 118, -52, -107, -51, -122, 106, 12, 43, 23, 111, -60, -79, -20, 57, -28, 99, -106, -87, 74, -18, 71, 44, -26, -6, 80, -124, 34, -69, 27, 46, -15, -97, -71, 84, 30, -121, -36, 65, -46, 66, -34, 69, -127, -16, 100, 114, 38, -110, -24, -34, 82, 69, -75, 108, 42, 83, 103, -14, -54, 10, 85, 107, -1, 42, 41, 106, 4, 65, 122, -101, -45, 19, 32, -110, 61, 53, 73, -97, -119, -63, 96, 55, -103, -59, -84, -35, -64, 47, -58, -38, 8, 9, 3, 82, -109, -78, 124, 69, -2, -74, -55, 72, -26, 33, -110, 92, -48, 87, 81, 39, 95, -45, 121, -82, -75, -79, -104, 93, 37, -118, 108, 20, -49, -96, 74, -120, -89, 110, -36, 115, 69, 98, 99, -21, 48, 112, -42, -124, 7, 18, 32, -126, -47, 87, -33, -5, -83, -2, 61, 85, -31, -18, 109, -75, 75, -16, 57, 67, 90, 98, 54, -27, -79, 111, -119, 67, 106, -3, 43, 56, -56, -115, -118, 15, -80, -83, -83, 101, 116, 46, -89, 113, -38, 33, -49, -114, -90, -20, 59, -50, 27, -98, 41, 116, -73, 48, 92, -104, -5, 74, -91, 75, 49, 35, 9, 65, -47, 35, 17, 27, -112, -64, -80, -104, 0, -109, 55, 89, 11, 42, -22, 86, -125, 127, 1, -27, -64, 21, -119, 15, 79, 27, -2, -18, 36, 77, 47, -32, 81, -117, -107, 112, 52, 125, -116, -83, -34, -15, 31, -37, 19, -65, 28, -93, -102, 12, 83, 108, 88, -5, 121, -107, -71, -3, 65, 18, -99, -92, 103, -9, 57, 90, 93, 29, 13, -14, 122, 126, -32, 54, 90, -126, 10, -123, -94, 46, -90, -11, -93, -75, 23, -18, 36, 51, 8, 115, -122, -44, -59, -99, -127, 33, -107, -116, 11, -94, -94, 92, -51, 94, -15, -72, 78, 82, 10, -14, -81, -121, -57, -55, 4, -64, 89, -69, -26, 24, 10, -27, -44, 80, 3, 11, -7, 127, 109, 3, -20, -52, 92, 31, -80, -13, -127, -73, -61, -11, -1, 110, 52, 100, -72, -73, 29, -98, -55, -39, 14, 48, 71, 79, -60, -29, -61, 97, -48, -59, -61, -117, 89, -73, 95, -4, -8, -57, 21, -26, 31, 37, 32, -72, 77, -41, -111, 99, 62, 98, 117, -63, 103, -124, -96, -111, -84, -1, 7, -20, 47, 57, 15, -59, 66, 53, 47, 97, -94, 7, -56, 124, 83, 72, 81, 101, 77, 96, -40, 67, 112, 112, 112, 16, -127, 72, -127, -98, -73, -125, 78, 84, 107, 125, 12, 121, 57, -17, 68, -41, -75, -28, -26, -3, 125, -97, 82, -53, 8, -124, -118, -1, 47, 19, 64, -18, 38, 45, 84, 85, -52, 105, 109, -61, 1, -32, 72, -107, 20, -102, -40, -47, 67, 111, -72, -92, 88, -30, 61, -82, 116, -2, -127, 35, 72, 35, -51, 24, 21, -87, 21, 63, -82, -2, 70, -70, -118, -64, 15, -44, 93, 108, 62, -51, 84, -15, 72, 7, 102, -107, -112, -7, -72, 84, -24, -22, 53, 68, 68, 38, -64, 71, 27, 73, 40, -86, 111, -56, 22, 49, 88, -119, -42, 9, 121, 82, 22, -35, 113, 5, -112, 12, -71, 17, -31, 92, -4, 48, -40, -44, -41, -60, -82, -116, 5, 117, -95, -28, -54, 45, -32, 39, -119, -25, 126, -40, 95, -97, -88, -58, -3, -81, -84, -82, -122, 122, -20, 11, 74, 85, 117, -75, 77, 39, -81, -72, 108, 123, 104, 65, -60, 81, -104, 41, 63, -62, 65, 43, -84, -64, 35, -63, 78, -111, 55, -1, 123, 73, 125, -92, -76, -81, -106, 103, -125, 105, -102, 112, -57, 69, 30, 13, 41, 65, -47, 121, -111, 94, -21, -16, -87, -39, 87, 91, 48, 116, -80, 100, 25, -64, 87, 63, -7, -6, -104, 41, -17, -13, 32, 106, -35, -35, -119, 107, 66, 116, 119, -68, -94, 116, 40, 117, -36, 89, 69, -47, -47, -78, 89, -16, -15, -25, -29, -53, -72, -105, -83, -67, 110, 52, 76, -92, 90, 93, -34, -18, 105, -92, -76, -55, -80, 117, -122, -94, -59, 100, 96, -85, -16, 116, 84, 55, -72, -55, -63, 54, 111, -1, 116, 6, 5, 23, -62, -109, 93, -127, 113, 96, 66, -16, 29, -95, -77, -13, 74, -90, 122, -37, -109, -40, 46, -108, -73, 45, 91, -23, -117, 85, 111, -23, 83, 3, -75, -51, -68, 102, 81, -122, -38, 12, -115, -34, 91, -29, -114, 124, -31, 93, -92, -124, -31, -17, 23, 65, -27, -6, 105, 0, -127, -110, 66, 59, -107, -95, 38, 69, -58, 106, 55, 105, 23, -19, -38, 118, 85, -5, -14, 126, -42, 84, -11, 121, 75, 72, -88, 29, 20, -107, -128, -109, -124, 120, -109, -91, -102, -56, -45, -103, 61, -71, 123, -66, -75, 58, -84, -61, 59, 12, 74, 78, -58, -73, -59, -14, -24, 78, 37, 123, -56, -98, 120, -25, -49, -115, 41, 66, -90, -12, -88, -62, 44, 81, -59, 67, 78, -57, -128, -123, -108, -94, -34, 108, 115, 78, 112, -95, 48, 80, 94, 6, -84, 46, -6, 31, -35, 7, 75, -57, -41, -3, 3, -67, -89, 15, -36, -111, 115, -126, -111, 61, 42, 84, -107, -90, -103, 44, -29, -21, 75, 96, 42, 34, 74, 117, -10, -63, 122, -119, -78, -50, -78, 39, 112, 10, 29, -3, 79, -119, 50, 121, 29, -96, -87, 114, 86, -65, -104, -80, -43, -123, 41, 106, -22, 2, -2, -38, -30, 97, 44, -51, -115, 75, 86, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
```

So I get the same data for the 1008 first bytes, and after that, I don't get anything anymore.

Any idea how to correct this ?

Answer (score 3):

I had to solve a similar error. And the only related question was in this thread, which was still not solved. So had to search for reason and solution myself :).

The reason is that Android bluetooth seems to send the data in bunches of 1008 Bytes.
So you need to read from the stream in a while loop and concatenate the received bytes.

Here is how your code should be rewritten:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
int bytes;

while ((bytes = inputStream.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) > -1) {
          baos.write(buffer, 0, bytes);
          baos.flush();
}
byte[] message = baos.toByteArray();

// =================== other side =============================
byte[] message = Tools.concatByteArray(response, authorizationMessage);
outputStream.write(message);
outputStream.flush();
outputStream.close(); // <-- important! so the receiver knows that it is the end of data
```

Answer (score 2):

Please check [Managing a Connection](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html#ManagingAConnection) part. As you can see;

> You should use a *dedicated thread* for all stream reading and
>   writing. This is important because both *read(byte[])* and *write(byte[])*
>   methods are **blocking calls**. *read(byte[])* will block **until there is
>   *something* to read from the stream**. *write(byte[])* does not usually
>   block, but can block for flow control if the remote device is not
>   calling *read(byte[])* quickly enough and the intermediate buffers are
>   full. So, your main loop in the thread should be dedicated to reading
>   from the InputStream.

When i started coding my *Reader Thread*, I tho *read(byte[])* method of InputStream will block execution until there are desired number of bytes. But it doesn't. I figured out that it does block until there is "something" to read from the stream (the part which i previously missed).

Consider your package is; 0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04 0x05 0x06 0x07 0x08 0x09, you sent it via OutputStream write and flushed. You might still get **only a part of it** (even 1 byte -> 0x01) in one read() call, and get the rest of it (0x02 and the rest) in the next read() call. In this case return value for read() will be equal to 1 and incomingBytes[0] will be 0x01 and the other elements will be 0

Comment: and how to be sure when message we expect is complete?! if I wait for 9 bytes and I get 1 and then later 8, but next time 9, next time 4 then 6, then 8, then correct 9 and so on...?!?! funny enought in protocol I am using I can user crc verification but when I got so cutted messages there is no point on crc til I am sure I have one whole message... So I need to implement logic of cutting, moving, joining byte array and messages are comming 200+ times per second... :( any help?

Comment: @Ewoks Exactly. The package size we used was more than 8bytes and later on, efficiency considerations made it expand much more. So you  won't ever regret implementing the logic you will need unless your package size is 1byte. I implemented a stream like functioning class collecting all bytes, converting them to fixed size packages when all package is received, throwing complete packages cleaning  the related bytes. That way, even if you receive 1byte or 2 packages in single inputStream.read() (which is highly possible using 8bytes of package size) you'll get 2 packages or none at all..

Answer (score 0):

Did you set any buffer size?
Normally you would read until there is no more data.

Comment: Yes buffer is initialized with 4096 bytes